# Array in array, I get an error: Type '[string, string, number]' is not assignable to type '[]'

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to have an array full of other array that contain string or numbers:

```
var mainarray: [] = [];
xy.forEach(function (foo) {
    var subarray: [] = ['test', 'test', 3];
    mainarray.push(subarray);
});
```

However I get this errors:

```
 Type '[string, string, number]' is not assignable to type '[]'.
Argument of type '[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

How do I have to declare the variable mainarray and subarray so that this works?

(Later I use this array to create a jsonstring)

Comment: With `orders.push(subarray);` you mean `mainarray.push(subarray);` ??

Comment: @zyz thanks yes of course I do mean that!  I corrected it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the type of your array as:

```
var mainarray: Array<number | string>[] = [];
```

Comment: Only the subarray has number or string in it, the mainarray has subarrays in it. So would it be something like this: `var mainarray: Array<Array<number | string>[]>[] = [];` This looks kinda confusing

Comment: Notice that for each type `T` the following are equivalent types: `Array<T>` and `T[]`. Alternative notations for the solution @xyz has given: `Array<(number | string)[]>`, `Array<Array<number | string>>` or `(number | string)[][]`

Comment: @nbar: No, I think a single `Array<number | string>` should do. It says that the content of `mainarray` is of type array which in itself can contain numbers or strings. Is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish here, so I can't provide a better answer without context, but you can do it like this:

```
let mainarray = [];
let xy = [1,2];

function test() {
     xy.forEach(x => {
         mainarray = [ ...mainarray, ['test', 'test', 3]];
     })

    console.log(mainarray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got another error message, while trying to run this code snippet:

> Type '[string, string, number]' is not assignable to type '[]'.
>     Types of property 'length' are incompatible.
>       Type '3' is not assignable to type '0'.

So your type declaration should be `string[] |number[]` or `(string | number)[]` and not just `[]`.
Consequently your code snippet should look like this:

```
var mainarray: [] = [];
xy.forEach(function (foo) {
    var subarray: string[] | number[] = ['test', 'test', 3];
    orders.push(subarray);
});
```